# Кастомный paginator на Angular

Tags: angular2, angular, angular4, angular5

Какая логика кастомного паджинатора на Angular2?

Я передаю на сервер:

- Номер страницы;
- Кол-во страниц для показа

Получаю с сервера:

- Общее количество станиц для вывода;
- Массив страниц для показа;

Не понятно назначение трехточия ( как на картинке) и как его показать([image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: просто захардкодить? я не вижу здесь никакой проблемы и даже надобности использования сторонних директив/компонентов, это очень простая задача

Comment: Я в принципе сделала вывод ссылок в ngFor  зависимости от кол-ва, но не понимаю назначения ... и как это реализовать. Они должны динамически появляться в зависимости от страницы наверное

Comment: я не вижу здесь смысла использования ngFor, если вам дали такой дизайн пагинатора - то вам лучше задать вопрос вашему дизайнеру, что такое `...` и зачем они нужны

Comment: Я ngFor динамически вывожу разное ссылок на страницы. А как без него?

Comment: я вижу фиксированное кол-во блоков `previous 1 ... 3 4 5 ... 100 next` - 9 блоков, которые можно захардкодить без надобности в использовании ngfor

Comment: Не, в засисимости от фильтрации будет приходить разное кол-во страниц (  от 1 до 2000). Скрин наверное вводит в заблуждение.

Comment: придет например 2000 страниц, блоки ж все равно будут `previous 1 ... 3 4 5 ... 2000 next`?

Comment: Да, согласна. Наверное должны всегда показываться:
previous, первая ... активная-1, активная,  активная +1, ... последняя, next
Но мне кажется на на ... тоже ставят какие-то ссылки

Comment: нет, они ничего не делают, `Show three dots when current page is greater than 2 and show three dots at the end when current page is awasy from end.`, для красоты

Comment: Тогда, да, хардкод - это выход) Спасибо Вам)

Comment: Простите, а как со статического элемента взять данные, в $event их нет, в local regerence тоже ((

Comment: извините, не понял вопрос?)

Comment: Я захардкодила в тегах li значения элементов массива - первого, предыдущего и т.п. и теперь по клику мне нужно их читать и передавать на сервер номер куда был клик)

Comment: создайте функцию `changePage` и передавайте туда параметр в шаблоне, также у вас должна быть переменная которая содержит номер текущий страницы `currentPage`

Comment: Да, так и сделала, я просто не могу данные из шаблона передать - в #ref их нет в $event тоже

Comment: не пойму что за `#ref` и зачем вам `$event`?

Comment: https://codeshare.io/5ReP9Q

Comment: #ref - local reference, передаю в функцию (click) = "getValue(ref)"

Comment: Ааа, поняла, я по-другому делала) СПасибо!!